# D3 v4 update in nested data, the best way

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following code which is simple enough to update a nested data model, but the `text(null)` section seems a bit weird.

I'm not sure if I'm doing it right or there is better way to do it:

```
var data = [
  {key: 1, values:[1, 2, 3]},
  {key: 2, values:[3, 4, 5]},
] 

function update(data) {
  var table = d3.select('#gogo')
  var tr = table.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data)
    .text(null)

  var rowEnter = tr.enter().append('tr')

  var td = tr.merge(rowEnter).selectAll("td")
    .data(d=>d.values)
    .text(d=>d)      

  cellEnter = td.enter().append("td")
  cellEnter.append("span")  
    .text(d=>d) 
}

update(data)
ref()
function ref() {
  setInterval(()=>{
    data.map(item=> {
      for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
        item.values[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
      }
    })
    console.log(data)
    update(data)
  }, 1000)
}
```

basically it just renders the following html code:

```
<table id="gogo"><tr><td><span>1</span></td><td><span>2</span></td><td><span>3</span></td></tr><tr><td><span>3</span></td><td><span>4</span></td><td><span>5</span></td></tr></table>
```

Please somebody gives me advise of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, there is a better way. Right now your code is confuse, it has some things that make no sense (like that `text(null)`) and, the most important, it cannot update the table for any different number of rows and cells... and that's the most important feature of an update selection.

This is my suggestion for your update function:

```
function update(data) {
  var table = d3.select('#gogo');

  var tr = table.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data);

  var rowExit = tr.exit().remove();

  var rowEnter = tr.enter().append('tr');

  tr = rowEnter.merge(tr);

  var td = tr.selectAll("td")
    .data(d => d.values);

  var cellExit = td.exit().remove();

  var cellEnter = td.enter().append("td").append("span");

  td = cellEnter.merge(td)
    .text(d => d)
}
```

Let's see it line by line.

First, the table selection:

```
  var table = d3.select('#gogo');
```

Based on that selection, we'll create the update selection for the rows:

```
  var tr = table.selectAll('tr')
      .data(data);
```

Then, based on that update selection, we create the enter selection for the rows:

```
  var rowEnter = tr.enter().append('tr');
```

After that, we merge the enter and update selection for the rows:

```
  tr = rowEnter.merge(tr);
```

This allows us to have any number of rows. Of course, to have a real update function, we have to set the exit selection as well:

```
var rowExit = tr.exit().remove();
```

Then, for the next level, which are the cells, we do pretty much the same thing, an update, an exit and an enter selection with `merge`:

```
var td = tr.selectAll("td")
    .data(d => d.values);

var cellExit = td.exit().remove();

var cellEnter = td.enter().append("td").append("span");

td = cellEnter.merge(td)
    .text(d => d);
```

Here is the demo with your `ref` function:

```js
var data = [{
    key: 1,
    values: [1, 2, 3]
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    values: [3, 4, 5]
  },
]

function update(data) {
  var table = d3.select('#gogo');

  var tr = table.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data);

  var rowExit = tr.exit().remove();

  var rowEnter = tr.enter().append('tr');

  tr = rowEnter.merge(tr);

  var td = tr.selectAll("td")
    .data(d => d.values);

  var cellExit = td.exit().remove();

  var cellEnter = td.enter().append("td").append("span");

  td = cellEnter.merge(td)
    .text(d => d)
}

update(data)
ref()

function ref() {
  setInterval(() => {
    data.map(item => {
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        item.values[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
      }
    })
    update(data)
  }, 1000)
}
```

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<table id="gogo"></table>
```

Finally, just to show you that now the update function really updates the table for whatever number of elements, I refactored your `ref` function to create data with a random number of rows, from 1 to 5, and a random number of cells, also from 1 to 5:

```js
var data = [{
    key: 1,
    values: [1, 2, 3]
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    values: [3, 4, 5]
  },
]

function update(data) {
  var table = d3.select('#gogo');

  var tr = table.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data);

  var rowExit = tr.exit().remove();

  var rowEnter = tr.enter().append('tr');

  tr = rowEnter.merge(tr);

  var td = tr.selectAll("td")
    .data(d => d.values);

  var cellExit = td.exit().remove();

  var cellEnter = td.enter().append("td").append("span");

  td = cellEnter.merge(td)
    .text(d => d)
}

update(data)
ref()

function ref() {
  setInterval(() => {
    data = d3.range(~~(Math.random() * 5) + 1).map(function(d) {
      return {
        key: d,
        values: d3.range(~~(Math.random() * 5) + 1).map(function(d) {
          return ~~(Math.random() * 20)
        })
      }
    })
    update(data)
  }, 1000)
}
```

```css
table,
td,
tr {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<table id="gogo"></table>
```

Comment: if you examine in the inspector, you will see the span is not in the output. What I want to do is to find a way to bind the nested data to arbitrary html element which is wrapped in the table 'cell'. And can be updated in the realtime. I have been struggling for hours and couldn't figure out the way.

Comment: I found a simple update with your solution is change one line to: var td = tr.selectAll("td span") and it gets done! And your solution finally lend me to the successful solution. Thanks!

Comment: @georgehu That won't work for all data structures. A better option is doing `td = cellEnter.merge(td).append("span").text(d => d)`, with a key function for the td update selection.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following way seems to more elegant:

```
    var data = [
  {key: 1, values:[1, 2, 3]},
  {key: 2, values:[3, 4, 5]},
] 

function update(data) {
  var table = d3.select('#gogo')
  var tr = table.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data)

  var rowEnter = tr.enter().append('tr')

  var td = tr.merge(rowEnter).selectAll("td span")
    .data(d=>d.values)
    .text(d=>d)      

  cellEnter = td.enter().append("td")
  cellEnter.append("span")  
    .text(d=>d) 
}

update(data)
ref()
function ref() {
  setInterval(()=>{
    data.map(item=> {
      for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
        item.values[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
      }
    })
    console.log(data)
    update(data)
  }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: You should put the accent in your solution on `.selectAll("td span")` to perform `.append("td").append("span")`, which is the most important part (I couldn't find this trick to keep the `span`). May I even suggest to modify the question to make it point exactly on this.

Comment: Well, I guess the solution provided by Gerardo Furtado is the best way to go. I would say those multiple text(d=>d) along the data propagation is not flexible enough. What if you even don't know the concrete attribute(In this example text) before hand? All we need is to propagate the data to the 'leaf' element and use the data. I"m not sure if I'm saying it correctly. But I did get the work done eventually.