# D3 v4 update pattern in a nested datamodel

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

Recently I'm learning D3 v4, which has many changes to version 3. I found a problem of implement the following update pattern which I used in v3 quite often:

```
    var data = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [3, 4, 5]
] 

function update(data) {
  var table = d3.select('#table');
  var tr = table.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data); 

  var rowEnter = tr.enter().append('tr'); 
  tr = rowEnter.merge(tr); 

  var td = tr.merge(rowEnter).selectAll("td").select("div")
    .data(d=>d); 

  var cellEnter = td.enter().append("td")

  var cellContent = cellEnter.append("div")

  cellContent.append("h1")
    .text("Title")

  cellContent.append("h2")
    .merge(td)
    .text(d=>d)

}

update(data)
ref()
function ref() {
  setInterval(()=>{
    for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
      for (var ii=0; ii<3; ii++) {
        data[i][ii] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
      }
    }
    update(data)
  }, 4000)
}
```

What I'm going to do is to attach a block of html snippet inside each of td 
element which is bound to array data. But this block of elements get cleaned up starting from the second update. How come v4 behave like that? Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50198949/5768908) I'm not sure about your goals here. However, if I understand your problem correctly, you have to select the `<h2>` element inside the merged update selection:

```
td = cellEnter.merge(td)
    .select("h2")
    .text(d => d);
```

Here is the modified snippet:

```js
var data = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [3, 4, 5]
]

function update(data) {
  var table = d3.select('#table');

  var tr = table.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data);

  var rowExit = tr.exit().remove();

  var rowEnter = tr.enter().append('tr');

  tr = rowEnter.merge(tr);

  var td = tr.selectAll("td")
    .data(d => d);

  var cellExit = td.exit().remove();

  var cellEnter = td.enter().append("td");

  cellEnter.append("h1")
    .text("Title")
    .append("h2")
    .text(d => d);

  td = cellEnter.merge(td)
    .select("h2")
    .text(d => d);

}

update(data)
ref()

function ref() {
  setInterval(() => {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      for (var ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++) {
        data[i][ii] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
      }
    }
    update(data)
  }, 1000)
}
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<table id="table"></table>
```

Comment: Wow!!! Thank you so much @Gerardo! Could you give me some explanation of td assignment line? I see you remove a merge there, I still could not twist my head over that.

Comment: The thing is that that should be an *update* selection. It's normal being confused initially, merging selections is notoriously hard to understanding.